# iOS Game Center invites not working at all in SANDBOX

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I´m trying to develop a multiplayer App & I´m using `GKMatchmaker` for that.
Unfortunately its `.inviteHandler` is never fired, it just says *"failed"* in the game center invite dialogue. The app works with **AUTO-MATCH** though.

I did some testing & made sure that

- 2 seperate sandbox gamecenter accounts are logged in.
- the test app runs on 2 devices (1 iPhone 4S & 1 iPad 2)

They still don´t connect.

I tried to start *DOODLE JUMP* (an existing iOS Game) und use the sandbox accounts for multiplay... they did not work either. Then i logged in with my *REAL NON SANDBOX* accounts to game center & THERE Doodlejump was working and the invitation was received successfully.

Do you have any ideas, how I could make my sandbox account work & receive my game center invitations?

Comment: I am having the same problem.When i start my game with 3player and while playing an game if 1player get disconnected the other two will also disconnected atomatically.I just dont understand y it happen.Though i set minimum player as 2.please help me

Answer (score 2):

Hope this still would be useful for someone...
Check two things in such situation:

- You set inviteHandler *just after* the local player has authenticated.
- The player you're trying to invite did allow game invites in their account settings. In case you had two test accounts, you could forget you disallowed it for both of them. In such case the push notification for invite won't even be sent to the other player.

Comment: What account settings are you referring to? Where would you modify those settings?

Comment: Settings.app → Game Center → Game Invites → Allow Invites switch

Comment: Strange, I don't see an entry *Settings.app → Game Center* (on iOS 6.1.4, that is)

Comment: Whoops, they've probably changed something in iOS 7. On iOS 6, try opening Game Center, and on the "Me" tab, pressing "Account: <xxx>" button → View Account. That should display the account settings.

Comment: Thx, that works (note to self: in sandbox environment on iOS 6.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Apple GameKit Programming Guide, a signed distribution build app will use the live GC environment, while everything else will use the sandbox. Unless you have the Doodle Jump source and build a debug version to run on your devices it will not work in sandbox mode properly.

Also you should make sure you are calling your inviteHandler method as soon after you authenticated a user as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the above don't work, try restarting your devices.  I created two test accounts and logged into two different devices with each respective account.  I couldn't get invitations to work, though automatching was working fine.  Restarting the devices somehow 'registered' them to get push notifications from Game Center, and invitations suddenly started working.